# Why 'No buffer space available' error when I have enough ports?

Tags: java, windows, networking, tcp, coldfusion

I have three servers running Windows 2003 with ColdFusion 9 (JRun 4) and ColdFusion 10 (Tomcat 7).

A few times a week one of the servers gets socket errors all over the place:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.168.1.3, port: 25;     nested exception is: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
```

and

```
SQLException while attempting to connect: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket to host and port: 192.168.1.11:1433. Reason: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect.
```

and

```
java.io.IOException: Socket read failed at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.read(AjpProcessor.java:323)
```

Of course I have been searching Google and Stack Overflow for this error and I have tried many possible fixes. Such as the MaxPorts registry value. The problem I have is that these servers are **not** running out of ports. They have plenty. I've been using TCPview and netstat (even CurrPorts logging all TCP and UDP changes to file) to analyse the situation. But every looks fine. At no time are there more than a few hundred connections in- and outbound.

Also, not all outgoing requests from the servers throw a socket exception. The websites running on these machines are reachable but sometimes (it seems random) a visitor gets the aforementioned socket errors.

Connecting to these machines with RDP is not a problem and doing a ping or telnet call from these servers to somewhere else is never a problem.

So, how can I be running out of ports when I have enough ports?

Comment: Because ports != buffers, and connections != ports.